# LTSpice - Voltage Comparator not working

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, comparator, simulated

My question is - why is CMP_OUT not going to HIGH (i.e. to 12V, P12V_IN) when INP_U1 is greater in voltage than INP_U2.

I think I haven't wired the LT1011 right. Do I have to do anything with the "B" and "S" pins?

I am open to using another part for the comparator as long as it is available in LTSpice.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is open-collector. Add a pullup resistor to +12.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will mark this as the answer in 8 minutes when stackexchange allows me to.