# Confused about this simple Comparator Circuit Output Waveform

Tags: ltspice, comparator, simulated

Below is my Circuit and Voltage Waveforms for the Comparator Circuit. My question is -- In the Highlighted area in the waveform - why is the V(CMP_OUT) not high since inp_u2 (blue) is higher than inp_u1(green) for this interval?

My goal is that CMP_OUT should be high whenever inp_u2 is higher voltage than inp_u1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your [other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/415714/95619) looks similarly rushed. Do take time to read the datasheets, instead of jumping to SE to ask a question that will, most likely, need hours to get an answer. It will only help you in the long run.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you for your feedback. I agree and I will try and improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OA does not work if the input is at V-.  There are limits to the common mode range.

This old part does not work to V- or Vee or below ground as some do.  Therefore connect -V = -0.5 or more.

Or keep Vin+/-  >0.5V  < Vcc-2

Comment: I get the same result when I connect the Vcc- to -12V: https://imgur.com/a/ZPUfbQL

Comment: You do not show the Vcm. Is that assumed to be floating?  Vcm= avg(in1,in2) w.r.t. 0V